# In scrapy 0.16 how do I change the file names of images downloaded via the images-pipeline?

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline

I would like to change the file names of downloaded images from the hash value it get's now to the image alt tag or something similar.

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class DocosPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item

class DocosImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        yield Request(image_url)

def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
    image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
    if not image_paths:
        raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
    item['image_paths'] = image_paths
    return item
```

I've tried overriding the image_key class, but I can't seem to get it right. Here's the class:

```
def image_key(self, url):
    image_guid = hashlib.sha1(url).hexdigest()
    return 'full/%s.jpg' % (image_guid)
```

I'm really stuck here any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you have put your image_key class but this code below is working fine for me

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    #Name download version
    def image_key(self, url):
        image_guid = url.split('/')[-1]
        return 'full/%s' % (image_guid)

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
```